# how to manage 100's of else if statement in javascript? better way?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript. I am trying to answer my quiz - classify urls. How can I improve my answer for classifying 100 urls.. my answer is not so efficient.. any help? thanks.

```
var pageURL = document.location.href;
var isHealth = pageURL.indexOf("http://www.domain.com/health/");
var isCar = pageURL.indexOf("http://www.domain.com/car/");
var isFuel = pageURL.indexOf("http://www.domain.com/fuel/");
var isRoadside = pageURL.indexOf("http://www.domain.com/roadside/");

if (isHealth > -1) {
return 'health';
} else if (isCar > -1) {
return 'car';
} else if (isRoadside > -1) {
return 'roadside';
} else if (isFuel > -1) {
return 'fuel';
} else return 'other';
```

Comment: usually a switch statement is the alternative to a bunch of elseifs

Comment: Just create an array with possible matches and loop through them.

Comment: use an enum instead of boolean values.

Comment: Just return the last part of the url:

`return pageURL.replace("http://www.domain.com/","");`

Comment: `switch (true) {}` :-) @Hogan

Comment: Note to improve readability. (sorry comments can't enter line breaks.) Else's are not needed if you return: 
`if (isHealth > -1) return 'health';
if (isCar > -1) return 'car';
if (isRoadside > -1) return 'roadside';
if (isFuel > -1) return 'fuel';
return 'other';`

Comment: @FabianLurz, that wouldn't work if there were additional segments.  E.g., `/roadside/winter/2014`

Comment: I think this may be the case of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @Samsquanch the OP says it's an assignment, which I can believe. A *real* front-end design would probably not involve this sort of hackery.

Comment: @Hogan What I shared *is* code. And although it works you should not do it.

Comment: Using `x.indexOf(y) > 0` is not a good way of doing a URL prefix check.  `'http://evil.org/#http://good.org/'.indexOf('http://good.org/') >= 0`.  Maybe check `x.indexOf(y) === 0` instead.

Comment: @Pointy I know this is some sort of assignment, but I think the hole OP is digging themselves into is thinking "this is the way I think it should be done, but I want to make it not suck" rather than "this is my approach to this problem, what's a better way to solve this problem?"

Comment: @Samsquanch yes, probably.

Comment: Think, is the problem in the else ifs or is the problem in making all those Booleans?   What if you had 1000s, what if there were more segments. Also is there a finite list of segments you are interested in or is it just you want to know if there is an additional segment? Also if it isn'ts a finite list do you want the last segment or the first one?  Think about the general problem.

Comment: @Samsquanch interesting to see how we psychoanalyse a quiz question!

Comment: @Hogan I never said anything else. You asked "how would that work if he need to check multiple booleans" so I answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use map object and `for` loop to check what url matches current page:

```
var urls = {
    health: "http://www.domain.com/health/",
    car: "http://www.domain.com/car/",
    roadside: "http://www.domain.com/fuel/",
    fuel: "http://www.domain.com/roadside/"
};

var pageURL = document.location.href;

for (var key in urls) {
    if (pageUrl.indexOf(urls[key]) > -1) {
        return key;
    }
}
return "other";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map them together like this, but I'm not sure if it's worth it:

```
var map = {
    'health': isHealth,
    'car': isCar,
    'roadside': isRoadside,
    'fuel': isFuel
}

for (var i in map) {
    if (map[i] > -1) {
        return i;
    }
}
return 'other';
```

That's the general approach.

---

### Better idea

But, your specific problem is easily solvable using regex:

```
var match = pageURL.match(/http:\/\/www.domain.com\/(.+)\//);
return (match && match[1]) || 'other';
```

---

See this live example:

```js
function test(pageURL) {
  var match = pageURL.match(/http:\/\/www.domain.com\/(.+)\//);
  return (match && match[1]) || 'other';
}

alert(test('http://www.domain.com/health/'));   // health
alert(test('http://www.domain.com/whatever/')); // whatever
alert(test('http://www.domain.com/'));          // other
```

Comment: Great, a downvote!! I only gave a better solution, as well as the solution that was selected in another answer (but mine is not broken)... Can't wait to hear about it...

Comment: @newbiedoodle I'm not rude, just a bit annoyed by people who use their mouse quicker than their brain. But 99% of the time I enjoy being here. :)

Comment: I also was thinking about this, just then I thought that maybe not all URL correspond to key in their URL. However if this is a case this solution is cool.

Comment: @dfsq Yeah, there's always a guessing part of almost every question. I thought about it as well, but since 4 of 4 examples are matching, just went ahead with it. It's still 2 lines vs hundreds. :)

Answer (score 1):

why not ?

```
    var pages = ['health', 'car', 'fuel'] 
    var page = pageURL.split('//')[1].split('/')[1] || -1;
    var index = pages.indexOf(page)

if (index !=-1) 
    return pages[index]
else
  return 'other'
```

Comment: Because that code will break on the first line in case of root url.

Comment: Shouldn't `return page[index]` be `return pages[index];`? Or even better yet, `return page;` as once you've figured out that it is whitelisted in the array you already have the value to return.

Answer (score 0):

["JavaScript Trie Performance Analysis"](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/) discusses how to use Tries in JavaScript to do compact, efficient prefix lookup.

It looks like most of your checks can be boiled down to "does the string s start with a URL prefix."  This kind of longest prefix check is exactly what Tries were designed to do.

If the bodies of your `if ... else if ... else` are not formulaic, you could store functions encapsulating those bodies as the value of the trie.